# adding custom attribute to fabric.js Object using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fabricjs

As told in the question I'm trying to add a custom property to a Fabric.js object.

I've tried

```
rect.customAttribute = value
```

but this stucks the compilation I get the following error:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'customAttribute' does not exist in type 'IRectOptions'.

I've also tried the function `toObject()` but couldn't find back my attribute and set it. Also after using `toObject()` then trying to set my added attribute with the previous method I logically get the same error.

```
let rect = new fabric.Rect(
    {
        left:0,
        top: 0,
        width: 60
        height:60,
        fill: 'orange',
        selectable: true,
        evented: true,
        name: 'rect',
        cornerColor:'red',
        cornerSize:5,
        borderColor:'red',
        borderScaleFactor: 5,
        noScaleCache:false,
        customAttribute:false
    })
rect.toObject(['customAttribute'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply create an interface which inherit from the original one. For instance , if i want to add an id to a rectangle :

```
interface IRectWithId extends fabric.IRectOptions {
    id: number;
}
```

And then use it as a parameter of your rect

```
const opt = {
    left: left,
    top: top,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    fill: 'rgba(98,98,98,0.8)',
    stroke: 'rgba(98,98,98,1)',
    hasControls: true,
    id: this.masks.length
} as IRectWithId;

const rect = new fabric.Rect(opt);
```

Comment: didn't tested it but I will and then upvote it. Many thanks for your answer

Comment: @grunk How should I do if I want to set values after object init: `rect.set("id", 6415)`.

I tried `rect.set<keyof IRectWithId>("id", 6415)` but I get this error:

`Argument of type 'keyof ITextWithId' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof IText'.   Type '"id"' is not assignable to type 'keyof IText'.`

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I've found so far is changing `IObjectOptions` definition and adding a `my`property to add any custom variable inside of it in `node_modules/@types/fabric/fabric-impl.d.ts` here is a sample

```
interface IObjectOptions {

  /**
  *Custom properties
  *
  */
  my?: any;
  /**
  * Type of an object (rect, circle, path, etc.).
  * Note that this property is meant to be read-only and not meant to be modified.
  * If you modify, certain parts of Fabric (such as JSON loading) won't work correctly.
  */
  type?: string;
  ...
```